# Passing data from UIView to Viewcontroller immediately Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiview, message-passing

I am trying to make an application which makes the user sign a specific area and than save the image to send it inside an E-Mail. But I am having a bit of a struggle with passing the image to my main viewcontroller. This is my code:

```
#import "LinearInterpView.h"

@implementation LinearInterpView
{
    UIBezierPath *path; // (3)
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder // (1)
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO]; // (2)
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:2.0];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect // (5)
{
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path moveToPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path addLineToPoint:p]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

}

+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}




@end
```

When I use the Prepareforsegue method, it is not working because the viewcontroller is not loaded again. I want to let the user sign the area, and then push a button on the same viewcontroller that inclused the subview, and create an e-mail with the code:

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Signature”];
```

How can I pass the data without first pressing a button or something. All help is appreciated very much!

Comment: If it's a `UIView`, you could set a custom delegate to notify the `UIViewController` that the signature has been completed.

Comment: And, how do i set a custom delegate, do you mean, expanding the code ''touchended'' with some lines and then use the Prepareforsegue method to send the image? Or am i confusing it all? @Larme

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when you do want to draw a signature, you just add a `UIView`.
So a possible way to do this is by using the Delegate Pattern.

In a few words and in a simple case (and I insist in "simple", because it won't be always the case):
ObjectA create ObjectB. 
ObjectA owns ObjectB, but how can ObjectB tell something to ObjectA ? Delegates !

In *LinearInterpView.h*, add :

```
@class LinearInterpView;
@protocol LinearInterpViewDelegate < NSObject >
-(void)linearInterpView:(LinearInterpView *)linearInterp didRenderSignature:(UIImage *)signature;
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id < LinearInterpViewDelegate > delegate;
```

In *LinearInterpView.m*, whenever you're "ready" (after a button click or whatever saying that you got your signature)

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:(linearInterpView:didRenderSignature:)])
    [self.delegate linearInterpView:self didRenderSignature:[self imageWithView:self]];
```

In your *YourUIViewController.h* :

```
@interface YourUIViewController : NSObject < LinearInterpViewDelegate>
```

When you call it in your *YourUIViewController*:

```
[yourLinearInterpView setDelegate:self];
```

In your *YourUIViewController.m*:

```
-(void)linearInterpView:(LinearInterpView *)linearInterp didRenderSignature:(UIImage *)signature
{
    [linearInterp removeFromSuperview];
    //Do whatever you want with signature
}
```